# How to do data visualization in Tensorflow JS?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, data-visualization

I am new to Tensorflow JS. I just created my first model and I would like to visualize data and track the loss in graphs...

I noticed Tfjs-vis library is depreceated and read only.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You could use something like p5.js

Comment: I looked up P5. It's not appropriate. I need something like Tensorboard but for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade TF and use Tfjs-vis library.

OR

You can use "Visor" as `tfvis.visor()` and do the visualisation.

The latest version documentation is given at the[js.tensorflow.org](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_vis/1.5.1/) site.

An illustration code is as follows :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-vis@1.5.1/dist/tfjs-vis.umd.min.js"></script>
<body>

<h2>TensorFlow Visor</h2>

<script>

const series = ['First', 'Second'];

const serie1 = []; 
const serie2 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  serie1[i] = {x:i, y:Math.random() * 100};
  serie2[i] = {x:i, y:Math.random() * 100};
}

const data = {values: [serie1, serie2], series}

tfvis.render.scatterplot({name: "my Plots"}, data);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output :

[image]